Disable popup to install app in mobile browser
Android users are seeing this "install app" prompt when visiting our site via mobile browser. What can I do within my Wordpress install or theme to disable this annoying popup from appearing?


I suspect this block of code is the reason:
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Tarheel Trailblazers - ">

Search your codebase first, your database second, for the source of that code, and remove or disable it.
